# How do i stop visual studio from highlighting only the current code block and fading out functions above and below?

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I've been searching for a while, and cant figure this out - vs 2019 currently highlights the current scope of text and fades everything else. I don't know, but it's killing me.. and i can't figure what it is thats doing this, and it does it with every theme, including the defaults.. How do you turn this off? any ideas? The only things i've added were a couple themes, but again it's doing this even on the default themes..

[image]

Comment: Please tag the specific version of Visual Studio

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Is this VSCode or Visual Studio? The former may have some extension installed like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=imagio.vscode-dimmer-block

Comment: I found it, answers below.. honestly in all the years, i've never seen that menu option before.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. of course, as soon I post this i find the answer.. For anyone else who runs across this... Toggle Focus Dimmer.. Ugh..

[image]